# Don't use "const char *" as a member of a class if you really mean "std::string"

Tags: c++, c++11

Update: So I checked my code with `valgrind --tool=memcheck` and saw about 200 hundred invalid reads, and I was invoking check() like 15 times so I figured something else was up.  It turns out I was moving character pointers around in my program, and in some cases I actually needed to copy strings.

It turns out that in `SomeClass` I was storing `const char *` members instead of `std::string` members.  I realized I actually wanted std::string members, since the data being pointed to originally were strings being generated in the make() method as variables inside the method.  The pointers I was storing in SomeClass were essentially pointing to memory addresses above the stack pointer.

By turning the data members to `std::string`, I'd be using the default copy behavior in the constructor, which would copy the whole string, instead of just the character pointer.

---

*Original question*

I've run into a strange memory clobbering issue and I don't know what's causing it.  I've figured out a workaround, but I'm mainly asking here because I wonder if there's some kind of C++ programming insight I lack since I don't see anything wrong with my original code.

Anyway, here's a simple check/report function for a unit testing framework I built:

```
/**
 * This version of check() wrecks data in result for some reason
 */
/*
void check(const std::string & test_name, const bool & result) {
    const std::string result_string = result?"OK":"FAIL!!!";
    std::cout << test_name << " " << result_string << std::endl;
}
*/
```

Here's the version that doesn't seem to clobber data:

```
void check(const char * test_name, const bool result) {
    std::cout << test_name << " ";

    if(result) std::cout << "OK";
    else std::cout << "FAIL!!!";

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

So, when I run this doing something like:

```
class SomeOtherClass;

class SomeClass {
private:
    const char * value1;
    const char * value2;
    SomeClass() = delete;
    SomeClass(const char *, const char *);
public:
    static SomeClass make(const SomeOtherClass &);
    const char * get_value1();
    const char * get_value2();
};

/**
 * I originally thought I was copying strings here, but I was just
 * copying string pointers.
 */
SomeClass::SomeClass(const char * value1, const char * value2) :
        value1(value1),   // >>> THIS IS WHERE I SCREWED UP <<<
        value2(value2)    // >>> THIS IS WHERE I SCREWED UP <<<
{}

SomeClass SomeClass::make(const SomeOtherClass & soc) {
    /**
     * In my original class, I generated strings to assign to const
     * char pointers.  As soon as the make() method returns, the
     * memory locations of these strings are supposed to be released
     * (I think).
     */
    const char * value1 = "some string";
    const char * value2 = "some other string";
    SomeClass tmp(value1, value2);
    return tmp;
}
const char * SomeClass::get_value1() const {return this->value1;}
const char * SomeClass::get_value2() const {return this->value2;}

SomeClass sc = SomeClass::make(SomeOtherClass());

// At this point, sc == {value1 = "some_string_1", value2 = "some_string_2"}
check("test1", std::string(sc.get_value1()) == "some_string_1");
// SOMETIMES At this point, sc == {value1 = "test1", value2 = "OK"}
check("test2", std::string(sc.get_value2()) == "some_string_2");  // fails (not supposed to)
// SOMETIMES At this point, sc == {value1 = "test1", value2 = "OK"}
```

Using: `g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2`

Compilation flags are: `--std=gnu++11 -g3 -Wall -Wpedantic -O0`

See above, but for some reason sc gets clobbered when used as above.  Rewriting my `check()` function not to use that internal `std::string` variable seems to eliminate this bug.  I tried setting up a watch in gdb for sc but the watch doesn't fire, so I'm suspecting something is just overwriting data... I'm guessing it's something in `std::string`.

So like I said, I figured out my workaround, but I was just wondering if there's something I don't understand about using `std::string` in my `check()` function the way I did in my first example.  I've only been programming in C++ for about 5 months so I'm definitely not an expert.

Comment: Maybe you can fix the initialization of `sc` so we can actually compile the code and duplicate the problem?

Comment: Something somewhere in your code has undefined behaviour.

Comment: What is the point of having const bool & result parameter? I believe it should be just bool.

Comment: Can we see how value1 and value2 are defined and initialized?

Comment: Is there a reason result_string in the first `check` function (the broken one) is const?

Comment: I don't see what `sc` being *clobbered* has to do with the definition of `check()`, you don't even pass that object into the function. There's something else going on in your real code but since you haven't posted enough of it for someone else to try and reproduce the problem, we can't help you.

Comment: the code you show is fine and works. (although the const & bool is very odd). Your error is somewhere else

Comment: why are you passing a `bool` by `const&`? that is horrendously inefficient, `bool` is small enough to be passed directly in register

Comment: In the function, which brings you an issue, the std::string is in the function scope. So it is not possible to cause memory issues because of that. Once the execution went out from the function scope all the stack will be release.

Comment: Yeah I know about the const bool & being bad, but I was tweaking it trying to reproduce the problem.  I just left it in there when I pasted it here.

I'll put up the section of my code that's breaking in a minute.

Comment: can u run it under valgrind?

Comment: When you say *In my original class, I generated strings to assign to const char pointers* do you mean `std::string` objects local to `make()`? As currently shown your code should work because string literals have static storage duration, meaning their lifetime equals that of your program, so only copying pointers to those literals should work fine.

Comment: No, I meant compile-time-defined constant character arrays via `const char * string = "string data"`, so the English definition for "string", and not `std::string`.  I'm still a little fuzzy on where string literals are in functions that go out of scope... I thought I realized that I couldn't read from those locations once I left the make() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My psychic debugging skills tell me that `this->value1` and `this->value2` are pointing to the `c_str()` string from local std::string objects and haven't been properly allocated. Then when you pass the string and create a local string in your check function the strings are reconstructed in-place causing your pointers-to-nowhere to, by pure random luck/unluck/chance, point to your newly created strings with different values, causing the values of your object to appear to change.

Comment: I suspect this too.  @pm100 above mentioned running it in valgrind, and sure enough there's a bunch of invalid reads.  I'm gonna update my question so it fits the rules, but I think your intuition is correct.

Comment: Some further information, I've been shuffling constant character pointers around in my program, and this problem seems to be associated with pointing to strings whose source was text in a file stream (`std::ifstream`).  Valgrind was seeing me move pointers to data that no longer existed because instead of copying strings, I was copying pointers and transacting those, thinking the strings would copy, and then I'd close the streams... so it looked like I did misunderstand how transacting const char pointers worked.